# rmi performance network traffic

Tags: java, jetty, rmi, resin

I  deploy a RMI Service ,write a RMI Client(Java SE project) to access it and is ok, but the some code in web project, I use wireshark to find that every RMI request sent from our client to our server containing the list of all jars in the classpath for the application.

My problem is similar to https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6664389

How to solve it?

Comment: Don't use the built in RMI? ;) You can use a plain socket or other RPC libraries which are much more efficient, if you really need to. However unless you know you have a performance problem I would leave the builtin RMI as it is.

Comment: I can't agree more ,but this is a Historical issues

Comment: If it hasn't been a serious problem for some time.... ;)

Comment: previous the issue is not serious
,because PV is small ...

Comment: Which why I suspect that RMI doesn't have a simple solution to make it more efficient.

Comment: The issues is possible caused by classload,but how to solve it

Comment: RMI manages the class loading for you. I don't know how to turn it off.

Comment: I also report a bug for jetty and Resin  ,separately link is https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JETTY-1540           http://bugs.caucho.com/view.php?id=5186

Comment: @Lawrey thanks .it is a JAVA bug ,I report the bug please see http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7193421

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the codebase feature. It is rather rarely used, particularly in the client -> server direction. It won't work unless the peer is using a security manager. In other words don't set the `java.rmi.server.codebase` system property at the client.

Or are you using Java Web Start as per the bug report and haven't told us?